# Download apps on Bluestacks with LAN only

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, lan, bluestacks

I am wondering if there is a way to download Bluestacks apps without an Internet connection? My laptop only has a LAN connection.

Comment: Problem solved, bluestacks fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a regular [downloadlink](https://www.bluestacks.com/download.html?utm_campaign=apps-dl-button-en) on the [Bluestacks](https://www.bluestacks.com/apps.html) webpage.